# Lex: identifier vs integer

Tags: c, regex, lex

I'm trying to create my own simple programming language. For this I need to insert some regex into Lex.
I'm using the following regex to match identifiers and integers.

```
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]* /* identifier */ return IDENTIFIER;
("+"|"-")?[0-9]+ /* integer */ return INTEGER;
```

Now when I check for example an illegal identifier like:

```
0a = 1;
```

The leading zero is recognized as an integer followed by the 'a' recognized as an identifier. Instead of this I want this token '0a' to be recognized as an illegal character.
How do I include this functionality? What regex do I have to adjust?

Comment: Actually what happens according to [maximal munch rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#Scanner) lex try to find a valid token from `0a` that is according to your rules is `0`  as integer then `a` as variable.  That is why `a+++b` is not error but correctly recognized as `a ++ + b` Rohit suggestion will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this in (F)lex is to create a second pattern for the error:

```
[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*  return IDENTIFIER;
[+-]?[[:digit:]]+        return INTEGER;
[+-]?[[:digit:]]+[[:alpha:]]   {
                           fprintf(stderr,
                                   "Incorrect integer '%s' in line %d\n",
                                   yytext, yylineno);
                           return ERROR;
                         }
```

The third rule will match any integer with a letter immediately following, and will signal a lexical error. (I'm assuming you've enable `%option yylineno`. If not, that will always report the error on line 0.)

An alternative might be to continue the lexical scan. In this case, you might want to rescan the offending alphabetic character. The easiest way to do this is in Flex is to use it's (idiosyncratic) [trailing context](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html#index-trailing-context_002c-in-patterns) operator `/`:

```
[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*  return IDENTIFIER;
[+-]?[[:digit:]]+        return INTEGER;
[+-]?[[:digit:]]+/[[:alpha:]]   {
                           fprintf(stderr, 
                                   "Warning: Incorrect integer '%s' in line %d\n",
                                   yytext, yylineno);
                           return INTEGER;
                         }
```

Now the third rule will match exactly the same thing, but after it matches it will back off to the end of the number so that the next lexeme will start with the alphabetic character.

You can also do this with the [`yyless()`](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Actions.html#index-yyless_0028_0029) macro:

> `yyless(n)` returns all but the first `n` characters of the current token back to the input stream…

So you could use:

```
[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*  return IDENTIFIER;
[+-]?[[:digit:]]+        return INTEGER;
[+-]?[[:digit:]]+[[:alpha:]]   {
                           fprintf(stderr, 
                                   "Warning: Incorrect integer '%s' in line %d\n",
                                   yytext, yylineno);
                           yyless(yyleng - 1);
                           return INTEGER;
                         }
```

Finally, as @CharlieBurns points out in a comment, you can just let the lexer return two tokens (one number and one identifier) to the parser, which will recognize a syntax error if that sequence is illegal in the language. In many programming languages, no grammatical program can contain an integer immediately followed by an identifier without some punctuation in between.

However, in many other languages, the combination is perfectly reasonable, particularly in languages like Lua where there is no explicit end-of-statement indicator, so

```
 b = 3 a = 4
```

is a valid program consisting of two assignment statements. As another example, in Awk string concatenation is represented with no operator and numbers are automatically coerced to strings if necessary, so

```
print 3 a
```

will print the concatenation of `"3"` and the value of `a`. Lua insists on whitespace in the above example; Awk does not.

And, for the ultimate, C(++) considers `3a` to be a single token, a "pre-processing number". If the token actually passes through the preprocessor, an error will be flagged, but the following program has no syntax errors:

```
#define NOTHING(x)
NOTHING(3a)
```

As a possibly more interesting example:

```
#define CONCAT2(a,b) a##b
#define CONCAT(a,b) CONCAT2(a,b)
static const int the_answer = CONCAT(0x, 2a);
```

So there is no "one answer fits all".

Comment: Another consideration would be to allow "0a" to be two legal tokens and let yacc sort out the syntax errors. Generally lex is used to find valid tokens, yacc for syntax errors. A lexer for C, for example, would return one token followed by the other and that would result in a syntax error.

Comment: Also, I have often found it easier to return '+' and '-' as tokens themselves and not attach them to the integer in the lexer. I do it in the parser, allowing whitespace between the sign and the number eg "int i = - 2;" So the lexer has a token named "UNSIGNED" rather than INTEGER.

Comment: I see the other answer is gone now. That is good, it was leading you astray. @rici knows what he is saying, the other answer was incorrect.

Comment: @CharlieBurns: If a number consecutive to a symbol is a syntax error, that's possible. But that's not always the case. (`awk 'BEGIN{a=3; print 4a}'` -- although `awk` accepts that as two tokens.) I'll edit the answer. A C lexer would not do that, though: `0a` is a "preprocessing number"

Comment: not sure I understand the 4a in awk. "0a" is illegal in C. 0xa would be ok, 07 would be ok. 4a would be two tokens, I can't think of a context in C where that would be legal syntax though. I could be wrong though.

Comment: @CharlieBurns: 4a in awk is the string concatenation of `"4"` and `a` (TIAS). I put an example of a valid C program with 3a in it into the answer. "4a" is definitely one token in C. (production `pp-number`)

Comment: thanks, that's very interesting. I understand how cpp sees it as a token, but I'm still trying to wrap my head around how C sees it. In the first example cpp returns nothing to C, in the second example it returns a valid number token. If the C parser proper ( not cpp ) saw "4a" I think it would return two tokens. You've done tricks to allow 4a in C source code, but in neither case does the token actually get to the C lexer which runs after cpp. I don't mean to argue, but that's how I see it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38921/discussion-between-rici-and-charlie-burns)

Comment: Rici and I chatted. He's right and knows more about this subject than I do.