# Handle number followed by letters in Flex

Tags: regex, flex-lexer

In some Flex/Lex code we have,

```
DIGIT       [0-9]
LETTER      [A-Za-z]
ID          {LETTER}{LETTER}|{DIGIT})*
NUM         {DIGIT}+(\.{DIGIT}+)?
```

So, `123` matches `NUM` and `abc123` matches `ID`.  In case of 
`123abc`, this matches `NUM` followed by and `ID`. However,
I want this to generate an error message instead of matching.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Have you tired putting ^ - start of string $- end of string onto the num regex? - ^{DIGIT}+(\.{DIGIT}+)?$

Comment: But in case of, 123abc+1.23, we get,
Error: unrecognized character 1
Error: unrecognized character 2
Error: unrecognized character 3
<ID, abc>
<PM, +>
Error: unrecognized character 1
Error: unrecognized character .
Error: unrecognized character 2
Error: unrecognized character 3
I want to second number to get recognized.

Comment: Will the + always be present? - ^([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)\+([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)$

Comment: No, that is math operator and you are seeing a simple mathematical expression.

Comment: Sorry I don't have a proper flex/lex environment to test on. These are my best efforts: ID -   ^([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]?)$  NUM -   ^([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)$

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work when put inside an expression. They work standalone though, well, partially. An ID begins with a letter followed by any combination of letters and digits. 
Getting flex/lex environment is not difficult. If you are using Ubuntu, `sudo apt-get install flex` is fine. For Windows, http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/flex.htm is good.

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain what is wrong with this question?

Comment: There's a parenthesis missing in your `ID` definition. (Also, I think defining LETTER and DIGIT is unnecessary, since you can use Posix character classes: `ID  [[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*` and `NUM [[:digit:]]+(\.[[:digit:]]+)?` (the latter does not allow `23.` nor `.5`, which are commonly used, but you are certainly entitled to ban those syntaxes).

Comment: You don't want to do this. If you start adding error rules to Flex definitions you will never stop, and you will start creating ambiguities. You should aim to let the parser handle all errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add an additional pattern to detect an error.

The following does not use macros, because I personally find them distracting. But the idea is the same.

```
[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*        { return IDENTIFIER; }
[[:digit:]]+"."([[:digit:]]+)? { return NUMBER; }
[[:digit:]]+"."([[:digit:]]+)?[[:alpha:]] { return BAD_NUMBER; }
```

The last pattern will only match if there is a letter immediately following a NUMBER, and will override the second pattern because of the longest-match rule.

By the way, a better pattern for a number is:

```
[[:digit:]]+("."[[:digit:]]*)?|"."[[:digit:]]+
```

That will match `23.` and `.56`, which many people expect to be valid numbers.

---

You might also find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19280985/1566221) interesting, particularly the examples from other programming languages. Most languages (other than C & family) do allow `123abc` to be scanned as two tokens, which usually leads to a syntax error anyway, and that is both the easiest and the most maintainable solution.