# How to end the tokenization of a sequence in Flex tool?

Tags: parsing, flex-lexer, lexer

I am using Flex (fast lexical analyser generator) tool. I have defined my reges as such:

```
  value             [0-9]|[1-9][0-9]*
  id                [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*
  plus              "+"
  ...
```

I have a few more keywords and operators defined like those. Here is one sample output that helps you understand my problem:

```
> 123
VALUE: 123 (123)
> name
IDENTIFIER: name
> 1230
VALUE: 1230 (1230)
> 0123
VALUE: 0 (0)
VALUE: 123 (123)
> 123x
VALUE: 123 (123)
IDENTIFIER: x
> x+
IDENTIFIER: x
OP_PLUS: +
```

As long as it fits a token to a proper class, it finishes and goes to the *start state* int the *DFA* again. Doing it just as it should. But I don't know how to handle this in Flex. 
And I believe numbers with leading zeros regex working just fine, yet it crashes because of the same reason. A proper output I am waiting for:

```
> (+ x 3)
OPEN_P: (
PLUS: +
IDENTIFIER: x
VALUE: 3 (3)
CLOSE_P: )
> 0123
SYNTAX ERROR
> 123X
SYNTAX ERROR
> 123+
SYNTAX ERROR
```

I don't want this sequence `123x` to be shown as like this:

```
VALUE: 123
ID: x
```

Instead I want to get a syntax error. Because `123x` is not a valid sequence for me. or `0123`, or `123+` etc.

Comment: Could you please be a little clearer about the difference between what you expect and what your code does? I honestly can't figure out what question you're asking.

Comment: I've added a clearer description, I suppose.

Comment: Here's a possibly similar question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32738412/handle-number-followed-by-letters-in-flex/32748601. And another one, mentioned in that answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19278859/lex-identifier-vs-integer/19280985

Comment: syntax errors are recognized during parsing. 123+56 should be valid expression, lex should not declare at lexical analysis 123+ as invalid token.